# Two classes, getting "type is not defined" error

Tags: f#

I have two classes, Foo and Bar, two distinct files, foo.fs and bar.fs

```
namespace Ganymede.Versioning

type foo = class 
    val Bar : bar
    new(input) = { Bar = input }    
    end


namespace Ganymede.Versioning

type bar = class
    val Test : string
    new (input) = { Test = input; }
    end
```

I get a "The type 'bar' is not defined." error inside class foo, for `val Bar : bar`

Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Files in a project must be ordered by dependency, so you need to put bar.fs above foo.fs in the project so that `foo` can see `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

See [this blog entry](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!444.entry), but briefly, if you don't specify a namespace or module at the top of a file, the code implicitly goes in a module named by the filename.  So if your project contains bar.fs and foo.fs (in that order, order matters) then to reference the type named 'bar' from file 'foo.fs' you must use 'bar.bar' (where the first is the module name, and the second is the type name).

Comment: But as you can see, I have a namespace definied?!

Comment: (Oops, sorry not to notice the namespace.)  Are the two files in the correct order in the project?